# Running node from a bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

Quite simply, I'm attempting to automate running a nodejs script using cron, however the script itself doesn't seem to be able to run the file. My script is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
node /var/node/assets/js/update.js
```

However, in running this, it returns that the beginning of the pathing is incorrect:

```
/home/dev/update.sh:2
node /var/node/assets/js/update.js
      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Is there something actually wrong with the bash, or does node have a specific way of doing this? I used /bin/env so that I could have the proper form of "node" regardless of version.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run node from within node.  The error message came from node and it looks like node was trying to run the command `/var/node/assets/js/update.js`.

I would make the shebang line specify bash rather than node.

The top line

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

means that what follows should be JavaScript code, not bash.

Comment: Curses! Was just about to type the same. An other option is also to include the javascript directly inside that file.

Comment: Hm, in that sense though, wouldn't it mean that if I just provided the path it would work? Because when I only leave the path, it errors with such: http://pastie.org/pastes/7899197/text

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't follow.  I see the error, but what exactly do you do to cause the error?

Comment: A bit late to tha party, but I guess... since this is a node environment, you can simply require your code. Never did that and not tested. @Rogue

Comment: @MaximilianHaindl 10 years later and I believe you'd be correct for both time periods. That said, I think for this task I would prefer calling into my node application through bash, as opposed to spreading out my node application in various places like cron.

Answer (score 22):

You are already running node on the first line in an unmodified environment.

then on the second line you supply the command `node /var/node/assets/js/update.js` to that node process.

How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
node /var/node/assets/js/update.js
```

Comment: Nope, this seems to stall when running (regardless of which script I run)

Comment: How is this answer different from what @Ray is saying?
What was your solution in the end?

Comment: I somewhat gave up on using the env node variable, and just made my script using bash instead. I merely ticked Ray's since his answer was first :)

Answer (score -5):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

node /var/node/assets/js/update.js
```